# MySQL update rows from a table with rows from another one

Tags: mysql, sql-update

I am trying to move a chunk of rows from a table to another one, only selected fields.

The tables have different field names.

The destination table is `mkt_data.bknk1810`, the source table is `tiresia.equity_810_openings`. The data that needs to be copied is in columns `A, B, C, D` which need to be copied to columns `max, min, close, open` respectively.

The following code results in copying only the first row from the source table into all the selected rows of the destination table, which is not the desired outcome.

```
UPDATE mkt_data.bknk1810, tiresia.equity_810_openings SET
    mkt_data.bknk1810.max            = tiresia.equity_810_openings.A,
    mkt_data.bknk1810.min         = tiresia.equity_810_openings.B,
    mkt_data.bknk1810.close          = tiresia.equity_810_openings.C,
    mkt_data.bknk1810.open     = tiresia.equity_810_openings.D
 where (mkt_data.bknk1810.Date >= '2021-07-19' and mkt_data.bknk1810.Date <= '2021-09-09') and (tiresia.equity_810_openings.p_key >= 20210719 and tiresia.equity_810_openings.p_key <= 20210909);
```

Where is my mistake? Why does it copy only the first row?

**EDIT**

Sample data was requested.

The rows in the destination table are

```
Date                max   min   close open
2021-07-19 00:00:00 null  null  null  null
2021-07-20 00:00:00 null  null  null  null
2021-07-21 00:00:00 null  null  null  null
2021-07-22 00:00:00 null  null  null  null
2021-07-23 00:00:00 null  null  null  null
2021-07-26 00:00:00 null  null  null  null
2021-07-27 00:00:00 null  null  null  null
2021-07-28 00:00:00 null  null  null  null
```

While the ones in the source table are

```
p_key     A     B     C     D
20210719  28100 27460 27620 27960
20210720  27630 27060 27410 27570
20210721  27870 27310 27530 27490
20210722  27970 27580 27910 27630
20210723  27970 27580 27910 27630
20210726  28150 27760 27790 28100
20210727  28150 27760 27790 28100
20210728  27840 27350 27530 27660
```

The data from the source table needs to be moved into the destination table.

Expected outcome is thus:

```
Date                max   min   close open
2021-07-19 00:00:00 28100 27460 27620 27960
2021-07-20 00:00:00 27630 27060 27410 27570
2021-07-21 00:00:00 27870 27310 27530 27490
2021-07-22 00:00:00 27970 27580 27910 27630
2021-07-23 00:00:00 27970 27580 27910 27630
2021-07-26 00:00:00 28150 27760 27790 28100
2021-07-27 00:00:00 28150 27760 27790 28100
2021-07-28 00:00:00 27840 27350 27530 27660
```

Comment: To me moving a chunk from 1 table to another implies an insert rather than an update. Please add sample data and expected outcome to clarify.

Comment: @P.Salmon the rows in the destination table exist already, and insert with where clauses are not supported in mysql

Comment: insert with where clauses are not supported in mysql  - not so where is available using an INSERT..SELECT and INSERT on duplicate key..

Answer (score 0):

It turns out you only nneded to add a simple

`and (mkt_data.bknk1810.Date= CONVERT(tiresia.equity_810_openings.p_key, CHAR));`

at the end of the query I posted.

Leaving this out for ref.